# How can I declare a variable to read from a different table column?

Tags: sql, excel, postgresql

I need to run a query and this query needs to run depends on the data in my excel file. So I supposed to create a ETL job to read this excel file to the temp table. User can change the Ques_P_id on different date, so I can read it to my temp table.

There are three column in my temp table:

```
   Report_name      | Ques_P_ID |        Ques_R_ID  

   AAA              7(could be 1~12)        132
   BBB              8(could be 1~12)        032
```

And I have another sql script to generate AAA report base on Ques_P_ID. Right now I want to do if the report_name =AAA and Ques_P_ID = 9 then run the query like this:

```
select a.contr_id, a.ques_r_id, a.ques_P_id, 
       max(case when ques_d_id = 320 then ques_d_id else NULL end) as "8-320",
       max(case when ques_d_id = 321 then ques_d_id else NULL end) as "8-321"
from PODS.v_questionnaire_results_master A
left join PODS.v_questionnaire_results_detail B on A.ques_r_id = B.ques_r_id
where 1=1 
and a.update_date = '20160824'
and a.ques_p_id = 8
and a.contr_id <> ''
group by 1,2,3;
```

This query will generate the report AAA report based on the ques_p_id = 8

```
contr_id    ques_r_id   ques_p_id   8-320   8-321
42315221    284806        8           320   
44501488    282575        8           320   
12817427    284460        8           320   
11336635    284864        8           320   
53040071    282691        8                   321
50408289    284398        8                   321
```

So I want to make the ques_p_id to variable can read the temp table if the ques_p_id = 1~9 then use 1~9 on my report query. So I need to help to declare this variable on my query.

If I need to identify the ques_p_id in my temp table  I should do like this right?

```
Declare @P  int
Set @P = select (ques_p_ID) from temp_table_excel
select * From generate_AAA_report(@P);
```

And also this script

```
max(CASE WHEN ques_d_id = 320 THEN 320 END),
           max(CASE WHEN ques_d_id = 321 THEN 321 END)
```

ques_d_id will change the number by p_id, if P_id = 9, 
it will change to WHEN ques_d_id = 520 THEN 520 END.....etc......

```
ques_p_id   ques_m_id   ques_d_id
    8          1           320    
    8          1           321
    8          1           322
    8          1           323
    8          2           324
    9          1           445
    9          1           446
    9          1           447
    9          2           448
    9          2           449
    9          2           450
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, then you best bet is a SQL function that takes `ques_p_id` as a parameter. With some tweaks to your query that looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION generate_AAA_report(p_id integer)
RETURNS TABLE(contr_id text, ques_r_id int, ques_p_id int, "8-320" int, "8-321" int) AS $$
    SELECT a.contr_id, ques_r_id, p_id, 
           max(CASE WHEN ques_d_id = 320 THEN 320 END),
           max(CASE WHEN ques_d_id = 321 THEN 321 END)
    FROM PODS.v_questionnaire_results_master A
    LEFT JOIN PODS.v_questionnaire_results_detail B USING (ques_r_id)
    WHERE a.update_date = '20160824'
    AND a.ques_p_id = p_id
    AND a.contr_id <> ''
    GROUP BY 1,2,3;
$$ LANGUAGE sql STRICT STABLE;
```

You could add a second parameter to the function for the `update_date` field so that you can use the same function for other dates as well. You should then probably also add a field to the table that is being returned from the function to identify which date it is for.

You can then generate a report like this:

```
SELECT * FROM generate_AAA_report(9);
```

The report is of course just the output from a query. If you want to save it, you can use this query in a `COPY` command to create a CSV file that you can open in Excel again, or you can make a physical table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE AAA_report_3 AS
  SELECT * FROM generate_AAA_report(3);
```

Note that the function returns a table so you should use it as a row source (in the `FROM` clause of the query).

Comment: Thank you for helping ,it helps me.

Comment: Hi Leo, I did not see you post a new question with your additional problem. Post that and I'll have another look at it. Basically, the solution would be to make the other data also a parameter, possibly an array of values like `generate_AAA_report(8, [320, 321])` or `(9, [520])`. But that would break the code of the above solution so making a new question is probably best so that it gets more attention from other users as well.